# How can I relocate the "i" (info button) in jQuery's Galleria Classic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I'm working with jQuery's Galleria Classic and would like to make a modification. I would like to instead of having a picture counter at the bottom of the image informing you of what number picture you are on, I would prefer a picture title. I want the title to change with each picture just like the counter. Is this possible?
Files I’m using:

- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4
- Galleria v 1.2 prerelease 1.1
- 2010-11-23 galleria.classic.css

Not sure if these questions are CSS or JavaScript questions.

Comment: you've got a lot of reading ahead of you! .. look at css for the button positioning.. but most of all, good luck!! ..and read, read, read :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I just needed to be pointed in the right direction. I'm good now on the positioning of the "i" button, but still not sure on where to start with changing the picture counter to a picture title. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Use this page to manage titles: [GitHub Galleria Documentation](https://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/docs/options/data_config.rst)